Will a Two-Routers Setup Work with a Laptop Running Cloudflare Warp Zero Trust?
I’m setting up a two-routers configuration to retain my residential country IP while traveling, and I need advice on whether this will work with my corporte laptop, which uses Cloudflare Warp Zero Trust.
(we are authorized to use a commercial VPN 30 days/year abroad but I don't trust their VPNs)
Here’s the setup:

At Home: I have a GL.iNet Beryl Router running a WireGuard VPN server, connected to my ISP router.(along with port forwarding configuration)
While Traveling: I’ll use a GL.iNet Opal Router as a WireGuard VPN client, connected to the Airbnb router or similar networks. The goal is to route all traffic from the Opal router back through my home network, ensuring a connection via my residential IP.

My corporate laptop is configured with Cloudflare Warp Zero Trust, which I understand creates its own secure tunnel for all internet traffic. I want to know:

Will Cloudflare Warp on the laptop bypass the WireGuard VPN tunnel from the Opal router?
Is there a way to configure this setup so that personal traffic from the laptop routes through the WireGuard VPN (home IP), while company traffic stays routed through Warp?
Would this setup work seamlessly for non-company devices, even if the laptop remains restricted by Warp’s routing policies?

IT told me that it works with a commercial VPN but no clue about this private vpn solution.
Any guidance or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Please stop voting to delete your question then immediately restoring it. Wether or not you’ll be able to connect to both VPN(s) will primarily depend on the configuration of the corporate VPN (since you’ll have bill ability to change it). Fundamentally there is no difference between a commercial VPN and a “private” VPN.

I have heard cloudflare uses TCP but wireguard uses UDP and as a conclusion I thought the combo may not work?

The only difference would be the firewall rule.

what kind of rule? is there a rule to detect traffic coming from wineguard?

Within a Firewall you have to specify if the traffic will be UDP or TCP. If you disabled your firewall then there would be no difference between the two VPN(s).

so if they disable the UDP then I won't have access? is there a way to check if UDP is authorized through my laptop?

It’s your system. It would be your firewall. Who is “they” exactly? All I said was the only difference between the two VPN(s) would be the firewall rule to allow TDP or UDP traffic.  As they would be separate ports they would require their own firewall rule anyway to function. I will be unable to help you. Driving into the mountains for 72 hours.

Thanks
they = IT security team
